# Integrating Hyprlinkr with Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, autofac, hyprlinkr

I'm trying to **integrate [Hyprlinkr](https://github.com/ploeh/Hyprlinkr)** in a WebAPI project **with Autofac.**
I've started writing the custom `IHttpControllerActivator` but I **get the following exception** when trying to resolve the controller:

> No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the
>   scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates
>   that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by
>   a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web
>   integration always request dependencies from the
>   DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime,
>   never from the container itself.

Here's how the class looks like:

```
public class AutofacControllerActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public AutofacControllerActivator(IContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        _container = container;
    }

    public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        var linker = _container.ResolveOptional<RouteLinker>(
            new TypedParameter(typeof(HttpRequestMessage), request));

        return (IHttpController) _container.Resolve(controllerType,
            new TypedParameter(typeof(IResourceLinker), linker));
    }
}
```

How do I **get the lifecycle issue fixed**?

Comment: How do you register your `RouteLinker` in the container? And if it was already registered why do you need a custom `AutofacControllerActivator` because if the `RouteLinker` is in the container you can use it in your controller constructor?

Comment: The `RouteLinker` has a runtime dependency on the `request`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write you own `IHttpControllerActivator` because you can register the `RouteLinker` itself  in the container.

You just need the help of the `RegisterHttpRequestMessage` method which makes the `HttpRequestMessage` resolvable from the container.

So your `RouteLinker` registration will look something like this:

```
builder.RegisterHttpRequestMessage(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
builder.Register(c => new RouteLinker(c.Resolve<HttpRequestMessage>()))
       .InstancePerApiRequest();
```

Now you can depend on the `RouteLinker` in your controllers:

```
public MyController : ApiController 
{
     public MyController(RouteLinker routeLinker)
     {
          //do stuff with routeLinker
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it! I went for `builder.RegisterType<RouteLinker>().As<IResourceLinker>().InstancePerApiRequest();`